# I am trying to set custom sound for notification android

Tags: android, kotlin

Setting custom notification sound for android doesn't seem to work. 
I am not such what I am doing so wrong. Here is my code:

```
  val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

   val urlsound = Uri.parse("${ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE}://"+R.string.packagename+ "/" + R.raw.sound_notification)

            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build()

            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    //.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setSound(urlsound)

                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

Everything else seems to be working just fine, but the custom sound just never comes.
Any idea of how to improve the code to play the custom sound?

Answer (score 0):

You propably need to create a Notification [Channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). After Android 8 all notifications pass through a channel. When this channel is created you can set a sound but you cannot change it afterwards. If you need all your notifications to have different sounds you can create a new channel everytime and delete the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `audioAttributes` to set sound method.

```
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(urlsound, audioAttributes)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

And remember don't add default Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND it will override any sound passed.

And make sure sound file is in raw folder.

Comment: I tried the audioattributes, but seems audioattributes are not required for NotificationCompat.builder.

Answer (score 0):

From `Android 8.0` you need to add a channel for each notification. So you have set sound during notification channel creation.

Put sound file inside the `raw` package and pass the id of sound and necessary attribute you want to use it. It will create your `Notification Channel` with sound

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private fun Context.createChannel(channelId: String,
                                          importance: Int,
                                          soundResId: Int? = null,
                                          shouldVibrateAndLight: Boolean? = null,
                                          channelName: String? = null,
                                          channelDescriptionRes: Int? = null) {
            val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)

            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance).apply {
                if (channelDescriptionRes != null) description = getString(channelDescriptionRes)
                if (soundResId != null) {
                    val sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/$soundResId")
                    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                            .build()
                    setSound(sound, audioAttributes)
                }
                shouldVibrateAndLight?.let {
                    enableVibration(it)
                    enableLights(it)
                }

            }

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
```